# What does "FB" for a fuse mean?

Tags: fuses, replacement

I have a blown GE 250v 20a FB WB27X27316 that I need to replace.

Unfortunately, GE doesn't have them in stock for another 3 months. I want to replace it with another off-the-shelf fuse, but I don't know what "FB" means (is it just Fast Blow)?

Are there other parameters that need to match? Because I couldn't find spec sheet from GE for this fuse. 
Will any ceramic 250V 20A fuse do?

Answer (score 5):

*I want to replace it with another off-the-shelf fuse, but I don't know what "FB" means (is it just Fast Blow)?*

FB does mean 'Fast Blow'.